# React inline styling

Tags: reactjs

How to apply inline styling in order to have a background-image ? the following code doesn't work

```
Header = React.createClass({
    render(){
    let headerStyle = {
        backgroundImage : url('about.jpg')
    };

    return (<header className="intro-header" style={headerStyle}>
    <div className="container">Some text</div></header>);

    }})
```

it returns an error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a string value:

```
backgroundImage: "url('about.jpg')"
```

just like you'd do with the standard DOM CSS API. You don't want `url('about.jpg')` to be interpreted as JS.

Answer (score 0):

Inline style are like this;

```js
let headerStyle = {
        backgroundImage : "url('about.jpg')"
    };
```