# React Styled Component space between components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have several [styled component](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)s in a row with a image.
I just need to add a space between `HeaderLink`s.
I've tried following way but it doesn't work.

```
const HeaderLink = styled.a`
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1.5em;
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  HeaderLink + HeaderLink {
      margin-left: 1em;
  }
`;
```

> HeaderLink1|HeaderLink2|Image|HeaderLink3|HeaderLink4

So I want to add margin between HeaderLink1&HeaderLink2 and HeaderLink3&HeaderLink4.
How can I use `styled component` in `styled css`?

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444060/react-inline-styling It should be what you need.

Comment: Yeah, it brought me an idea. Using ${HeaderLink} instead of just HeaderLink solved problem. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just used `${HeaderLink}` instead of `HeaderLink`.